# Can I perform a set method over an atribute which has not been instanciated in the constructor method?

Tags: java, oop, methods, attributes

I'm working over a (functional) Java code developed sometime ago, and for a given class its construct method only presents one attribute, while further down the code there is a set method for an attribute not previously mentioned in the construct.

The code structure is something like this:

```
public class A{

    public int attribute_1;
    public int attribute_2;

    public A(attribute_1){
        this._at1 = attribute_1
    }

...

    public void setAttribute_2(int attribute_2){
        this._at2 = attribute_2
    }
}
```

Can someone shed a light on why this works?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The default value (int 0) is assigned to attribute_2 when constructing the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, FOR int datatype this default will be zero for more detail [refer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

So it does not matter when you assign the value. This is only true for Instance/class variables. While if you have any local variable within local method/function must be declared and initialized with value.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what the question is, but in the example you gave, when you call the constructor, `attribute_1` will have the value given in the constructor arg, and `attribute_2` will be 0.

Later, if you call `setAttribute_2`, the value of `attribute_2` will be set to whatever is given in the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Default value of int is 0 if not assigned during construction. Request you to read about initialization of an object in java. [Enjoy!](http://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/InitCleanup1.html)